# not able to get selected value form ng-model

Tags: angularjs

in below conditon i am unable to get selected value,  but where i am not used the directive **ng-show** i am able to get ng-model value.

perticularly i am unable to get value for $scope.SCENTER_NAME of select box.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6" ng-show="mode==1">
                    <h6><strong>LEGAL ENTITY:</strong>
                        <select id="LEntity_updated"  ng-model="SCENTER_NAME" ng-options="cntr.CENTER_NAME for cntr in myCenter track by cntr.CENTER_ID" class="form-control">
                        </select></h6>
                </div>


                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <h6><strong>SBU:</strong><select id="updatedPrgm" ng-model="SelectedPRGM_NAME" ng-options="prgm.PROGRAM_NAME for prgm in myPrgm track by prgm.PRGM_ID" class="form-control"></select>
                    </h6>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <h6><strong>Department:</strong>
                        <select id="Department_updated" ng-model="selectedDep" ng-change="OnDeptChange()" ng-options="cntr.Dept_name for cntr in myDepartment" class="form-control" required></select></h6>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <h6><strong>Sub Department:</strong>

                        <select id="subdept_updated" ng-disabled="mysubDepartment.length == 0" ng-model="SelectedSub_Dept_Name" ng-options="cntr.Sub_Dept_Name for cntr in mysubDepartment" class="form-control" required></select></h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" ng-click="Send_data(mode,selectedtxid)">Approved</button>

                                    </div>


$scope.Send_data= function (mode, selectedtxid) {

                    var postData = {
                  pg: $scope.SelectedPRGM_NAME,
                  pcent: $scope.SCENTER_NAME,  // unable to get the value here.
                        dpt: $scope.selectedDep,
                        subdept: $scope.SelectedSub_Dept_Name,
                        rmemp: $scope.selectedEmployee_mgr.originalObject,
                        req: $scope.selectedEmployee,
                        modee: mode,
                        SelectedDsbu: $scope.SelectedDsbu,
                        selectedtxid: selectedtxid,
                        selectedReporties: $scope.reporties
                    };

}
```

let me know i done any mistake or any code changes required.

Comment: Do you understand what the `ng-show` directive does?

Comment: Where did you try to access the selected value? Post the relevant code. Tell us what you expect it to do and what it does instead. I would also advise, for your own mind-safety (and ours) to respect the standard naming conventions, rather that randomly mixing camel case and uppercase and abbreviations.

Comment: updated the code. after button click approve, i am unable to get the selected value of  'LEntity_updated' selected vale.